# How to add read-only privileges on DFS Folder for Windows 2003 R2?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, windows, dfs, windows-server-2003-r2, dfs-r

I just install a DFS system on different servers. My replication group consists of Windows 2003 R2 and Windows 2008 R2 servers. The replication itself works well. On the Windows 2008 R2 server I can enable the membership to read-only, in the Windows Server 2003 R2 not. Is there a way to enable this function, for example to update the DFS system OS independent or with some CLI Commands?

Here is the dialog of Windows 2008 R2 member:
[image]

And here the same dialog of Windows 2003 R2 member:
[image]

Comment: You really should strongly think about upgrading that 2003 server if you can.  There are a lot of DFS-R improvements between 2003 and 2008R2

Comment: Yes we think about and plan the migration of the Servers. The first step is to migrate the replication away from a third party software for replication. because we can't update all server at the same time.

Answer (score 3):

[One-way replication is not supported or recommended](http://blogs.technet.com/b/askds/archive/2009/06/23/recovering-from-unsupported-one-way-replication-in-dfsr-windows-server-2003-r2-and-windows-server-2008.aspx) in DFS-R in Windows Server 2003 R2. It is possible to configure it to work in a "read-only" sort of manner, but that wasn't a tested or designed configuration for the product and you may end up with unintended consequences.

Comment: I understand that this is a hub and spoke scenario, it is not right that the hub send data to spoke? Send the spoke also data to the hub? What consequences could appear?

Comment: This is only for security reasons, normally there write nobody to the spoke's. But if anybody delete something I will protect the other systems.